# Why is NSBundle bundleIdentifier optional?

Tags: ios, swift

Just wondering why `NSBundle bundleIdentifier` is optional.

[image]

Is there a reason it could be nil?

Answer (score 11):

If you're just building an executable, running a script, or using the Swift REPL, `bundleIdentifier` will be nil.

For example, make a file called `test.swift` containing.

```
import Foundation

print("\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier)")
```

then run it from the terminal with

```
swift test.swift
```

it will print nil

Answer (score 6):

Referring to [bundleIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1418023-bundleidentifier):

> The bundle identifier is defined by the CFBundleIdentifier key in the
>   bundle’s information property list.

Because there is a key in the app's `.plist` file called `CFBundleIdentifier` could be null:

[image]

*If you are seeing different key names, right click and choose "Show Row Keys/Values".*

In this case, it should be `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's because `NSBundle` has to pull this information from the Info.plist.  Remember, the `bundleIdentifier` method is there on all `NSBundle` instances, not just the main bundle, and other bundles might not be as well-put-together as the main bundle.